# Sort posts in a specific way

Tags: php, wp-query

I currently have 6 posts that are under the category 'services'. Each service has the_content and 1-2 documents (Brochure and/or T&C and an external form)

Now, let's assume those 6 posts have the ID 1,2,3,4,5,6 but I want it in as 2,5,3,1,4,6.

Is that possible? If so, how would I be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with native query parameters like this:

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post__in' => [2,5,3,1,4,6],
    'orderby   => 'post__in',
]);
```

This combination will instruct WP to fetch specific posts by ID *and* order them in the specific way that you supplied IDs.